# How do I get different Configs into Custom Plugin Implementations of the same Interface?

Tags: moryx

Simplified example:

I have a custom plugin `ICustomPlugin`

```cs
public interface ICustomPlugin : IPlugin
{
}
```

and two implementations which require information from different configs. (Of course this only makes sense if the interface would define some common API but let's keep it simple)

```cs
public class CustomPluginWithConfigA : ICustomPlugin 
{
}

public class CustomPluginWithConfigB: ICustomPlugin 
{
}
```

Since I want to use both implementations my ModuleController should start both of them

```cs
[ServerModule(ModuleName)]
public class ModuleController : ServerModuleBase<ModuleConfig> 
{
    ...
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        foreach (var converter in Container.ResolveAll<ICustomPlugin>())
            converter.Start();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, what is the clean way to get only the config information that each implementation needs into the respective classes `CustomPluginWithConfigA` and `CustomPluginWithConfigB`?
Referencing the classes in the controller or providing the same config to all implementations feels equaly wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options and it depends whether your implementations `CustomPluginA` and `CustomPluginB` are located within the module, e.g. they are fixed components rather than flexible plugins, or loaded from additional **MORYX packages**.

In the first scenario you can simply add your components configuration values to the `ModuleConfig` and inject the config into your plugin, because a modules config is registered in its local container by default.

```cs
// In the module config
[DataMember]
public int ValueForA { get; set; } 

[DataMember]
public string ValueForB { get; set; }

// In CustomPluginA: Injected
public ModuleConfig Config { get; set; }

public void SomeMethod()
{
   var a = Config.ValueForA;
}
```

If on the other hand your plugins are fully located outside your module **or** can be extended with external implementations, you should use `IConfiguredPlugin<TConfig>` for your plugins and define a plugin base config. You will then instantiate your plugins with a factory passing their dedicated configs until we implement [MORYX-Platform#10](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/issues/10).

```cs
public class MyPluginConfig : IPluginConfig
{
  [DataMember, PluginNameSelector(typeof(ICustomPlugin))]
  public virtual string PluginName { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int ValueForA { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomPlugin : IConfiguredPlugin<MyPluginConfig>
{
}

[PluginFactory(typeof(IConfigBasedComponentSelector))]
public interface ICustomPluginFactory
{
  ICustomPlugin Create(MyPluginConfig config);
}

// In your module config
[DataMember, PluginConfigs(typeof(ICustomPlugin))]
public List<MyPluginConfig> ConfiguredPlugins { get; set; }

// In your plugin
public class CustomConfigA : MyPluginConfig
{
  public override PluginName { get { return nameof(CustomPluginA); } set { } }
}

[ExpectedConfig(typeof(CustomConfigA)]
[Plugin(LifeCycle.Transient, typeof(ICustomPlugin), Name = nameof(CustomPluginA))]
public class CustomPluginA : ICustomPlugin
{
  public void Initialize(MyPluginConfig config)
  {
    var typed = (CustomPluginConfigA)config; // MORYX takes care of correct type
  }
}

// In your controller Initialize
Container.LoadComponents<ICustomPlugin>(); // Load from all DLLs and packages
// In Start
var factory = Container.Resolve<ICustomPluginFactory>();
foreach (var config = Config.ConfiguredPlugins)
{
  var plugin = factory.Create(config); // Calls Initialize with the config
}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: The `PluginNamesAttribute` was renamed to `PluginNameSelectorAttribute`